# Maven-shade tika-app returning empty string

Tags: java, apache-tika, maven-shade-plugin

I was using tika-app-1.20.jar to extract metadata and content from files. Reason why I shaded Tika, was to remove dependencies clashing with each other in the project which was built already.

The shaded jar works fine no import problem with the new shaded-names ,but then its returning "EmptyParser" for all files leading to no content being parsed.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test1.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.20</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>tika-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
        <relocations>
          <relocation>
            <pattern>org.apache.tika</pattern>
            <shadedPattern>com.test1.tika</shadedPattern>
          </relocation>
        </relocations>

        <filters>
          <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </filter>
      </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I removed the *.SF,*.RSA,*DSA to remove invalid signature digest error. My intuition is that , some property file is getting removed in this process that maps the parser with filetype.

Comment: Did you [try following the Apache Tika troubleshooting steps to see what has gone wrong?](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika) If not, what happens when you do?]

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the parsers are not getting recognized and only "empty parser" is returned by the autodetectparser

Comment: You must be zapping the service files under `META-INF` that Tika needs. Look at the pom file for the Tika App itself to see an example of how to make a single jar of Tika without loosing key bits - Tika App is already a single jar shade